# Array for Wordpress Avatar Size and Class

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I tried to set size and class for wordpress avatar in comments but I couldnt.

```
<?php if ($args['avatar_size'] != 0) echo get_avatar( $comment, array('class'         => 'media-object') ); ?>
```

I want to set avatar in comments to 70x70 size and "media-object thumbnail" class then show it.

What is my mistake?

I re-wrote comment function in html5blank for better css but as a last thing, I couldnt do this.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<?php if ($args['avatar_size'] != 0) echo get_avatar($comment,'70',$default, $alt,array('class'=>array('media-object','thumbnail'))); ?>
```